# Why isnt the water from bottle dropping in the tub(volume of bottle/tub doesnt matter) until the level equalises?

Tags: fluid-statics

I can't seem to understand why water in the bottle wont drop down until the water level equalizes so pressure is same in any horizontal plane. As you can see just at tip of bottle,the pressure inside bottle would be higher due to the water level above it 
And yes the bottle is closed from the top, so I assume the answer has to do something with the pressure created due to that?

Edit:- ok so pressure inside the little pocket is $P_{outside}$ (I'll just call it $P_o$)
from the time the bottle was opened

so, the pressure at the tip should be $P_o + D \cdot g \cdot h$ where $h$ is height of water level from tip to the level in the bottle and $D$ is density

but from the bigger container's perspective, the pressure there is $P_o$

[image]

Comment: Please use MathJax and proper grammar when writing your question. We like to keep things looking readable and professional on the site.

Comment: i am really new here...i dont know how to use math jax but grammar...yes sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

If the bottle is closed above, the total pressure due to the weight of the water of the bottle is $\rho gh$ at the tip.

There is much more than 1000 m of air on the water surface. Even air density being about 1/1000 of the water at the sea level, it is enough to weight much more than the water inside.

By experience, it is necessary more than 10 m of water to overcome the air weight.

Comment: But when i closed the bottle, the pressure of air around it was inside it too, it didnt have vacuum, so the pressure of Po is already there? Am i wrong here?

Comment: @VanSHOE With the bottle closed, it is enough that a small portion of water escapes to increase the air volume inside, decreasing its pressure as a consequence.

Comment: Oh, so some of the water does come down but its unnoticeable, i understand thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The pressure in the bottle (at the top), Pi, is lower than the pressure outside:   Po = Pi + Dgh.

Comment: I tried with different water levels however the level stayed constant at the level I left, what i mean to say is, h had no impact on anything...

Comment: Since atmospheric pressure can support a water column about 33 feet high, you will not notice much pressure difference in a bottle.